# Dimensions of different spaces with linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

I have an exercise with different properties to show. I was able to prove some but I am stuck with others.

Let $V$ and $W$ be two vector spaces with finite dimension and let $L: V \rightarrow W$ be a linear map. Let $S \subset  W$ be a subspace of $W$.
Show that

(a) $L^{-1}(S)$ is a subspace of $V$ ;

(b) $\dim L^{-1}(S)= \dim L^{-1}(S \cap \text{im } L)$;

(c) the restriction of $ L$ to $L^{-1}(S)$ is a linear surjective map: $$L_{\big|L^{-1}(S)}: L^{-1}(S) → S \cap \text{im } L;$$

(d) $ \ker L_{\big|L^{-1}(S)} = \ker L$;

(e) $\dim L^{-1}(S) = \dim \ker L + \dim(S \cap \text{im } L)$.

I was able to prove (a), (d) and (e) but I do not know what to do with the others.
I think they are so obvious that I don't know how to show them properly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(b) is misleading because the equality still holds if you remove $\dim$:
$$L^{-1}(S)=L^{-1}(S\cap\mathrm{im}\,L).$$

Indeed, for $x\in V$, we have:

$$x\in L^{-1}(S)\iff L(x)\in S\iff L(x)\in S\cap\mathrm{im}\, L\iff x\in L^{-1}(S\cap\mathrm{im}\,L).$$

(c) is now saying that you have a linear surjection
$$L:L^{-1}(S\cap\mathrm{im}\,L)\to S\cap\mathrm{im}\,L.$$

This means:

- The image of $L^{-1}(S\cap\mathrm{im}\,L)$ under $L$ is precisely $S\cap\mathrm{im}\,L$. Both inclusions should be very straightforward.
- Both $L^{-1}(S\cap\mathrm{im}\,L)$ and $S\cap\mathrm{im}\,L$ are vector spaces. This should be clear: Intersections of vector spaces are again vector spaces, and preimages of vector spaces under linear maps are vector spaces again.
- This restriction of $L$ is linear. This is obvious because already the unrestricted $L$ is linear.

Answer (score -1):

Well, in this sort of scenario, there's only one thing you can really do to show statements $b$ and $c$:

You need to find a basis for $L^{-1}(S)$. So try to think in these terms:

- What is the definition of $L^{-1}(S)$? How do you write it mathematically?
- What is a natural candidate for a basis of $L^{-1}(S)$? How can you show that it is of the smallest possible size? And that it is indeed spanning?

Once you know how to answer these questions, $b$ and $c$ should follow together.